# Do the different characters in Temple Run affect gameplay?

Tags: temple-run

Do the different characters in Temple Run change the game in any way except visual appearance?

Do they have different skills, or is it all just visual changes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, they don't, they're just skins.

Comment: any reference ?

Comment: There was an interview with the game's developers published in a printed newspaper in Israel about a month ago, in it there was a tips section where they mentioned this. I don't have the article scanned and couldn't find it online, though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes: when you die, it changes the message you receive about your death.

Comment: If by "comments" you mean the messages you see when you die, that's hardly considered "gameplay", I still consider them "visual appearance"

Answer (score 0):

It makes a difference only in the case of Usain Bolt where you can use bolt distanace power. Rest all behave same.

Comment: AFAIK,  Bolt only appears on Temple Run 2.

Comment: Yes you are right. I just shared it thinking the question is generic for all temple runs.

Answer (score -1):

There are differences.

- **Guy Dangerous and Scarlett Fox** - the primary characters and mediocre ones.
- **Barry Bones** - His speed is same as Guy's but has a much refined and lovely grip on run.
- **Karma Lee** - She is very fast
- **The Rugby Player** (Don't remember his name) He has some properties of Karma Lee and Barry Bones.
- **Rahi Raja** - Ah my favourite! The most balanced character of the game.